# rename files using array values vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I need to rename files in a folder based on values that I have created in an array. I am running into problems because I am not sure how to declare the part of the file that needs to be renamed.

The files look like: Xnnnnnnnnnnnnnn_stmt-n.pdf where n= any number between 0-9. What I am trying to have it do is look at the n value part that comes after stmt- and rename it to a set of array values that I already have declared. The n value can be anywhere from 1-400. I want the script to say that if the n = the array value then rename that part of the file to the array value.

Here is a few example array values that I have created. 1="aa" 2="ab" 3="ac" ... 50="bx" .. 150="fv"....all the way to 400="ql".

Here is the code that I have so far that is not executing:

```
Const INPATH = "\folder"
Const OUTPATH = "\folder"

' check that the directories exist. 
dim fso: set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
if not fso.FolderExists(INPATH) then
err.raise 1,, "Path '" & INPATH & "' not found"
end if
if not fso.FolderExists(OUTPATH) then
err.raise 1,, "Path '" & OUTPATH & "' not found"
end if

dim Array(400)
Array(0)=" "
Array(1)="aa"
Array(2)="ab" ' this would continue until 400
Array(400)="ql"

dim infolder: set infolder = fso.GetFolder(INPATH)
dim file
for each file in infolder.files

dim name: name = file.name
dim parts: parts = split(name, ".")
dim nanname: nanname = left(parts(0), 21)
dim value: value = right(parts(0), 1)  
dim newname
dim newvalue 
    if value = 1 then newvalue = Array(1)
    if value = 2 then newvalue = Array(2)
    if value = 400 then newvalue = Array(400) 
        newname = nanname & newvalue & "." & parts(2) 'parts 2=pdf
        file.move fso.buildpath(OUTPATH & newname)
    endif 

next
```

One of the major issues that I am having is trying to find a way to declare 'value' because the value part of the filename can be any number 1-400. Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to encode the numbers 1 ... 400 (676) to "aa" ... "pj" ("zz") or are those just placeholders for arbitrary strings? To get the number between "-" and "." you could use Split(parts(0), "-")(1).

Comment: What I am trying to do is create an array for all "values", read the value from the filename and if the value is "1" then rename it to "aa", if it is "2" rename it to "ab", if it is "3" rename it to "ac".........all the way to 400...... if it is "400" then rename it to "ql". I am now realizing that I dont know how to define what part "value" is because it could be 1,2 or 3 characters long. So I cant really use Split(parts(0), "-")(1) because it could be more than (1) character long.

Comment: Please excuse me for what I said about "I am now realizing that I dont know how to define what part "value" is because it could be 1,2 or 3 characters long. So I cant really use Split(parts(0), "-")(1) because it could be more than (1) character long". I am getting frustrated and my brain is not working. That (1) represents the second part of the split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem is that "Array" is a VBScript function and you cannot use it as a variable name. Here is an updated script. I haven't tested it, but you should be able to get the idea.

```
dim fso: set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
if not fso.FolderExists(INPATH) then
  err.raise 1,, "Path '" & INPATH & "' not found"
end if
if not fso.FolderExists(OUTPATH) then
  err.raise 1,, "Path '" & OUTPATH & "' not found"
end if    

dim LetterArray(400)

dim vChrLoop1 = 0 'First letter loop
dim vChrLoop2 = 0 'Second letter loop
dim vArrayPointer = 0 'Total counter pointer

Do Until vArrayPointer = 400 'loop through every value
  Do Until vChrLoop2 = 25 ' loop until the letter "z"
     LetterArray(vArrayPointer) = Chr(97+vChrLoop1) & Chr(97+vChrLoop2)

     vChrLoop2 = vChrLoop2 + 1 'move to the next letter for the second letter
     vArrayPointer = vArrayPointer + 1 'increment the pointer
  Loop

  vChrLoop1 = vChrLoop1 + 1 'move to the next letter for first letter
  vChrLoop2 = 0 'Reset the second letter loop to "a"
Loop

dim infolder: set infolder = fso.GetFolder(INPATH)
dim file

for each file in infolder.files

  dim name: name = file.name
  dim parts: parts = split(name, ".")
  dim nanname: nanname = left(parts(0), 21)

  dim aValue(1)
  aValue = Split(parts(0),"-")
  dim value: value = aValue(1)
  dim newname

  newname = nanname & LetterArray(value) & "." & parts(2) 'parts 2=pdf
    file.move fso.buildpath(OUTPATH & newname)
next
```